# Why is the Google Calendar API not accepting my bearer token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, google-calendar-api, bearer-token

I am trying to learn OAuth 2.0 by walking through walking through making Google API call using Firefox 28.0 and [REST Client v2.0.3](http://restclient.net/).

1. I went to the Google Developer [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) site.
2. I signed in using my Google credentials
3. Selected "Calendar API v3" `.readonly`
4. clicked the "Authorize APIs" button
5. Then I clicked "Exchage authorization code for tokens" and got the access token `ab31.4.CDEfG_HI1JkKMNoPQR5S9tuvW_x2yzabcDEFGhiJklMnOpqRs-T6uvwXyza5BcdEFGHiJK3L`
6. From the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list), I use the URL https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList wtih the GET HTTP action
7. In RESTClient I create a header with the name "Authorization" and set the value `ab31.4.CDEfG_HI1JkKMNoPQR5S9tuvW_x2yzabcDEFGhiJklMnOpqRs-T6uvwXyza5BcdEFGHiJK3L` to the from "Access token:" box from the OAuth 2.0 Playground.
8. With an empty `Body` I click `SEND` and I get an authorization error (the playground says my token is still valid for another 30 minutes)

The error's header is:

```http
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 162
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 18 Mar 2014 19:17:35 GMT
Expires: Tue, 18 Mar 2014 19:17:35 GMT
Server: GSE
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

and the body is:

```js
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The header needs to be set to `Authorization: Bearer ab31.4.CDEfG_HI1JkKMNoPQR5S9tuvW_x2yzabcDEFGhiJklMnOpqRs-T6uvwXyza5BcdEFGHiJK3L`. You need the word "Bearer" preceding the token.